# How to show document Preview next to task-edit page? (Alfresco share)

Tags: templates, share, alfresco, freemarker, document-preview

Is there a simple way of providing a preview of a document attached to the task, next to edit-task page itself? (It will be always 1 pdf attached)

[image: previewsample]

I saw [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117565/task-edit-document-preview-component-alfresco) but they do not provide working solutions to my problem.

Comment: What would happen if you had multiple documents attached to the workflow?

Comment: For every attached document it might generate a button which will show the specified content. But in my process only one document can be attached so it does not matter.

Comment: It is very hard to change or customise the current edit-task page? How much you're flexible to create a new page?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your question? I could use some help. Thank you!

Comment: @prachi_shah_c2 provided a very good answer here https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/document-preview-in-edit-task-page/td-p/213401